# How can I render/Display Another Razor Page onto another Razor page that is not a partialView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to asp.net core. I have checked other questions and answers on Stack , but unfortunately none helped resolve my issue.

So I have created an empty Asp.net core Razor Pages project. I created a Model folder in the file hierarchy. Within the Model folder i created 2 class models. 1- Category 2- Character. (Relationship. Each category can contain a list of characters BUT each Character can belong to only ONE category.)

I then created 2 sub folders within my pages folder named Category and Character. I right clicked and created a Scaffold of each the Category and Character. Which generated its respective CRUD pages (Index, Create, delete, Details, Edit) The location of these are

Pages/Category.index.cshtml etc.

Pages/Character.index.cshtml etc.

I want to try and render the Category.index.cshtml at the bottom of my Pages/Index.cshtml. Similar to what Iframe does but without the borders and scroll bars. The whole Category/Index.cshtml to be a part of the Pages/Index.cshtml

Category Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HV.Model
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
        public string? CategoryImage { get; set; }


        public int CharacterId { get; set; }

        //creating a navigation property that represets the relation between the two classes Catgeory and Character
        public List<Characters> Characters { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Character Model

```
namespace HV.Model
{
    public class Characters
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        public string CharacterBio { get; set; }
        public string CharacterSecretIdentity { get; set; }
        public bool Charactergender { get; set; }
        public string CharacterTeam { get; set; }

        public bool CharacterGoodOrBad { get; set; }
        public string? CharacterImage { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        //Each Character will belong to a single Catgeory
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My main Pages/Index.cshtml body  that i want to render or display my categories index

```
<body>
    <div class="container bg-dark">
        <!-- Background image -->
        <div class="bg-image shadow-2-strong" id="intro">
        </div>
        <!-- Background image -->
    </div>
   

    <div id="content">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center h-100">
            <div class="text-white">
                <h1 class="mb-3 display-2">Welcome to HeroVerse</h1>
                <h5 class="mb-4">Best &amp; free guide to everything Superhero related</h5>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9B4TPnak1A" role="button" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Start Exploring</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg m-2" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/" target="_blank" role="button">Say Hi</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Add more content here to scroll through -->
    <div class="container text-white" id="content">
        <h2>CATEGORIES</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer euismod mi et odio tincidunt, sit amet bibendum arcu bibendum.</p>

      <!-- Render the Categories/Index.cshtml Razor Page as a partial view -->
      <div>
            @* @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Categrory/_Index.cshtml", Model.Categories)*@
           @* <component type="typeof(CategoryList)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />*@
           @* <iframe src="/Categrory/Index" style="width: 100%; height:100vh; border:none" ></iframe>*@
            <CategoryList />

       </div>

    </div>



    <div class="container">
        <h2>ABOUT</h2>
        <partial name="~/Pages/About/_IndexAboutPartial.cshtml" />
     
    </div>

    <!-- Add more content here -->

</body>
```

Comment: You can make the main content of the *Category/Index* page a partial, and then render that partial in the *Category/Index* and wherever else you want to within the application.

Comment: The generated Category/Index is just a page that show all the records, If you just wanna show all the records, you don't need to render the razor page, You just need to create a partial view show all records, Then render this partial view in your index page and pass model into this partial view.